# d3-tile zoom bug in Microsoft Edge / Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been building some web maps using d3, and I've run into an annoying bug with Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge: when zoomed in at a neighborhood/city scale, panning the map causes vector layers and raster tiles to lag and move out of sync. I can recreate this bug using one of Mike Bostock's Raster & Vector mapping examples. For instance, the bug appears if I remove the scaleExtent from this example and zoom to a point at a city/street scale:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9535021

Here is a version without the scaleExtent:

http://d3-raster-tile.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/

I suspect the issue has something to do with the initial scale value, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  margin: 0;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<svg></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-tile.v0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var pi = Math.PI,
    tau = 2 * pi;

var width = Math.max(960, window.innerWidth),
    height = Math.max(500, window.innerHeight);

// Initialize the projection to fit the world in a 1×1 square centered at the origin.
var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .scale(1 / tau)
    .translate([0, 0]);

var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);

var tile = d3.tile()
    .size([width, height]);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var raster = svg.append("g");

var vector = svg.append("path");

d3.csv("us-state-capitals.csv", type, function(error, capitals) {
  if (error) throw error;

  vector
      .datum({type: "FeatureCollection", features: capitals});

  // Compute the projected initial center.
  var center = projection([-98.5, 39.5]);

  // Apply a zoom transform equivalent to projection.{scale,translate,center}.
  svg
      .call(zoom)
      .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
          .translate(width / 2, height / 2)
          .scale(1 << 12)
          .translate(-center[0], -center[1]));
});

function zoomed() {
  var transform = d3.event.transform;

  var tiles = tile
      .scale(transform.k)
      .translate([transform.x, transform.y])
      ();

  projection
      .scale(transform.k / tau)
      .translate([transform.x, transform.y]);

  vector
      .attr("d", path);

  var image = raster
      .attr("transform", stringify(tiles.scale, tiles.translate))
    .selectAll("image")
    .data(tiles, function(d) { return d; });

  image.exit().remove();

  image.enter().append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "http://" + "abc"[d[1] % 3] + ".tile.openstreetmap.org/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[1] + ".png"; })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d[0] * 256; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d[1] * 256; })
      .attr("width", 256)
      .attr("height", 256);
}

function type(d) {
  return {
    type: "Feature",
    properties: {name: d.description, state: d.name},
    geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [+d.longitude, +d.latitude]}
  };
}

function stringify(scale, translate) {
  var k = scale / 256, r = scale % 1 ? Number : Math.round;
  return "translate(" + r(translate[0] * scale) + "," + r(translate[1] * scale) + ") scale(" + k + ")";
}

</script>
```